# New Function like VLOOKUP but based on two search keys

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

The A column is first name and the B column is last name in the spreadsheet I'm manipulating. In the other sheet it's the full name(but not necessarily just firstname + lastname)

HC is the spreadsheet I need to get the data from. This code will work if the person has a unique first name that is the same in both sheets : =VLOOKUP("*"&A2&"*",HC!$C$1:$I$400,7,False) but this isn't enough in my case. The *s known as wildcards check if this string is contained in another string regardless of it's position.

I tried =VLOOKUP("*"&A5&" "&B5&"*",HC!$C$1:$I$400,7,False) but that means the two strings have to occur one after the other. I need it to return if search_key1 is contained within the string regardless of accents(á or a) or case (A or a) and the same for search_key2 e.g. the string could be "Seárch_key1 kdslfj SEARCH_KEY2 akldfj" and this would return True and then give the 7th column.

```
   function VLOOKUP2(search_key1,search_key2,range,index){
  //is search_key1 contained in one of the cells in the range if so is search_key2 also contained in one of the cells in the range regardless of capitilization and diacritical marks

  // return the column specified by the index parameter 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you're asking for a custom function, but I think you could do this with two existing `vlookup` functions.

If your data on sheet `HC` looks like this:

[image]

Then on your lookup sheet, try this in cell `C1` (deleting everything below):

```
=arrayformula({"Result";if(A2:A<>"",iferror(iferror(vlookup("*"&A2:A&"*"&B2:B&"*",{HC!C:I},7,0),vlookup("*"&B2:B&"*"&A2:A&"*",{HC!C:I},7,0)),),)})
```

[image]

**HELP NOTES**

The inital vlookup tries to match `"*"&A2:A&"*"&B2:B&"*"` in `{HC!C:I}`. `{}` is used to create an array.

[image]

If not, then the `iferror` tries another `vlookup` to match `"*"&B2:B&"*"&A2:A&"*"`.

[image]

Another `iferror` deals with no match, removing `#N/A`.

[image]

Then the `if(A2:A<>""` only tries the above formula if there is a corresponding value in the same row, in Col A.

[image]

The final array `{}` places `"Result"` at the top of the column, with the main formula below. After the heading text, `;` forces a return in the array.

Within the vlookup, `0` denotes `false`. `1` would be `true`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Just a few questions, is the  very outer iferror thing does that just make it return blank instead of an N/A and the inner just makes it go to the second vlookup. I assume the 0 in VLOOKUP represents FALSE. The square brackets around the HC!C:I. The if(A2:A<>"") I assume that just checks if it's blank. I changed it to this =iferror(iferror(vlookup("*"&A3:A&"*"&B3:B&"*",HC!C:I,7,0),vlookup("*"&B3:B&"*"&A3:A&"*",HC!C:I,7,0))). This seems to work and I just drag it down to fill up the column.

Comment: I just need to add my custom function RMIRR(remove irregularities) the code is this function RMIRR(input){//irregularities
  input = input.trim();
  input = input.toLowerCase();
  input = input.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
  input = input.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  return input
} I tried this =iferror(iferror(vlookup(RMIRR("*"&A3:A&"*"&B3:B&"*"),RMIRR(HC!C:I),7,0),vlookup(RMIRR("*"&B3:B&"*"&A3:A&"*"),RMIRR(HC!C:I),7,0))). But it doesn't work and I'm not sure why. I assume it's some kind of syntax problem

Comment: I removed the first if error to see the problem it says input.trim() is not a function but it is I even tested the function with console.log(RMIRR("Álvaro Martín")) which returned alvaromartin. And I've used a NAMETOEMAIL function function NAMETOEMAIL(input) {
  input = input.trim();
  input = input.toLowerCase();
  input = input.replace(" ", ".");
  adr = "@email.com";
  input = input + adr;
  input = input.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
  input = input.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  return input;
}This works and it uses the trim method.

Comment: I've added help notes to the solution above. I don't use custom functions so I can't advise on them, but if you provide the cleaning 'logic' I might be able to add a `regexreplace()` function inside the code.